# Oscillation and Damped oscillation program

Tags: physics

I am trying to build a simple program where an object undergoes simple harmonic motion,
where a force is initially applied, than undergoes SHM until coming to a stop.
My problem is that my program runs forever without the object ever stops,(as if there is
no external force acting on the object to slow it down)

How could I add a force to slow it down to its initial equilibrium point?

Here is what I have so far:
given a mass, initial force applied, spring constant-K 
I calculate

amplitude = mass*gravity + Force(applied) / K
omega = sqrt(K/mass)
initPos = mass*gravity / K

to find postion at time t = initalPosition + amplitude*cos(omega*t)

but this system will never end, it keeps oscillating for ever.
How can I add a force to stop the oscillation over a period of time??

sorry for the long post!

thank you

Comment: Have you studied differential equations? You can include the various forces involved, including damping, in a differential equation, and find solutions either numerically or analytically.

Comment: I have a good knowledge of differential equations, but I dont see how you could apply one to this sort of problem. Do you know any simple examples to illustrate?

Comment: See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Damping, for instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can multiply by a damping factor, so $x(t)=x(0)+Acos(\omega t)\exp(-bt)$ where you choose $b$ to make it damp as fast as you want.

Comment: It probably doesn't need mentioning, but $b$ should be greater than $0$ for damping. If $b = 0$, you'll have no damping, and if $b < 0$, the oscillations will grow in amplitude without bound.